# Add Progress Bar's Class based on GridView column value: jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, gridview, progress-bar

I am having a grid, in which I have a column called "C" which specifies the C:\ Drive. In that column, I am showing the used space in bootstrap progress bar.

I have done binding the records with the gridview. Here, I want to change the progress bar class based on the used space. Suppose, if the used space is more than 90% then, i want to show progress-bar-danger else I want to show progress-bar-info.

```
The code, I have tried and the result I am getting is below:

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
                 <%# Eval("C") %>
             </div>
         </div>
     </ItemTemplate>                                
 </asp:TemplateField>

 jQuery:

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(".progress").each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                value = parseInt($this.find('.progress-bar').text());
            $this.progressbar({
                value: value
            });
            // Here, "value" gives the used space value.
        });
    });

</script>

 Result:
```

[image]
How to change the progress bar class based on the value also align the progress bar text align center? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `progress-bar-danger` class in your `.each` loop by checking the value.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".progress").each(function (index, elem) {
    var $this = $(this),
        value = parseInt($this.find('.progress-bar').text());
        /*
        $this.progressbar({
            value: value
        });
        */
    if ( value > 90 ) {
      $(elem).find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-danger');
    }
    // Here, "value" gives the used space value.
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
          60%
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 91%;">
          91%
        </div>
      </div>                
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using in a gridview, it may have more rows. but this one is not giving the result for me.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand why the gridview would prevent you from selecting all progress containers, since this is what you already doing. Can you explain to me what the problem is with that.

Comment: Here, I am loading gridview with the datatable from the db. The datatable may have more than 5 rows. For each row, I need to display the progress bar based on the value of the column "C". I need to loop and change the progress bar based on the condition.